# Symfony 3.4 to 4.4 - Call class out of routeLoader

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I´m Loading Routes with a Custom Service as follows:

```
additional_routes:
   resource: 'routeLoader:load'
   type: service
```

My routeLoader looks like that:

```
..

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use tt\myBundle\Entity\ContentPage;

class routeLoader{

    private $doctrine;
    private $router;

    public function __construct($doctrine, UrlGeneratorInterface $router){
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function load($resource, $type=NULL){
       ..

       $contentPageCollection =  $this->doctrine->getRepository('ttmyBundle:ContentPage')->findAll();

       ..
    }
}
```

After updating from 3.4 to 4.4 I get now the following error message:

> Class ContentPage::class does not exist in routeLoader:load (which is
> being imported from
> "..EDITED/config/routes.yaml"). Make
> sure there is a loader supporting the "service" type.

I already tried the following without success:

```
$contentPageCollection =  $this->doctrine->getRepository('ContentPage::class')->findAll();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `ContentPage::class` as string but need to use as keyword:

```php
public function load($resource, $type=NULL){
    ..
    $contentPageCollection =  $this->doctrine->getRepository(ContentPage::class)->findAll();
    ..
}
```

Comment: Sometimes you don´t see the easiest things, thank you.

Comment: When i have like 80 Controllers, i have to check all and include my entity´s now everywhere?

Comment: There exists refactoring tool called Rector that can help you do the most part of upgrade job https://getrector.com/